# Google Analytics Gtag Multiple Analytics Account Tracking IDs

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

From what I can see Google seem to be phasing out analytics.js now in favor of their tag manager.

How do I fire google analytics new gtag tracking code for multiple analytics accounts?

Something like this:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-108285779-2"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-108285779-2');
  gtag('config', 'ANOTHER CODE');
  gtag('config', 'ANOTHER CODE');
</script>
```

Comment: That should be correct, [See here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/)

Comment: I have a similar question but in my case i get to different id's. Should I add now another script src tag with the second id?

Comment: Hey @Niklas that was what fixed the issue for me: Additional async src tag with the additional code.

Answer (score 28):

**In short:**

> **Yes**, you can add the *same type* of product *multiple times* by calling `gtag('config', ...)` for each respective Google account + property ID you have.

**Details:**

It's 2021 and I had the same question but was too paranoid to trust this thread's top voted answer because it described a different experience than my own when testing how this works. Firstly, though, in order to answer OP's question in 2021 we have to look at **two** entries in Google's official docs, because neither entry fully answers the question but when brought together they can give us a bit more confidence in how to solve this:

- **Can I add more than one *type* of product using** `gtag('config', ...)`**?** (**Answer**: yes.) ([Docs](https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/devguide/add))
- **Can I add more than one of *the same type* of product using** `gtag('config', ...)`**?** (**Answer**: yes.) ([Docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/#configure_additional_google_analytics_properties))

Here's an example snippet of how I accomplished OP's scenario using JavaScript. If you try this in your browser's console you should see a unique script get added for each ID you set in the below snippet's `googleIds` array.

**Notes:**

- Notice that the snippet's `googleIds` array contains five IDs.
- Notice that, after running the snippet in your browser console, five `<script>` tags get set to the page, but that the snippet itself only explicitly built and set one of the  tags to the .
- The rest of the  tags get added after their respective IDs are pushed into the dataLayer, and after the first script is initialized (i.e. the  element is constructed + set to the ). The order of these two steps doesn't matter (i.e. You can initialize first and then push your IDs to the dataLayer, or push your IDs to the dataLayer and then initialize).

```js
// An array of IDs I want to load on the same page(s) at the same time
var googleIds = ["AW-00000000", "AW-00000001", "AW-00000002", "DC-00000000", "UA-00000000-1"];

// Setting dataLayer & gtag to window because I'm using a custom code text field in a tag management system
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.gtag =
  window.gtag ||
  function() {
    window.dataLayer.push(arguments);
  };
window.gtag("js", new Date());

// Flag used to ensure script only set with first ID, and rest of IDs are pushed to dataLayer
var gtagScriptExists = false;

// ID validation regex. Only tested with AW-*, but DC & UA are also valid prefixes
var validIdStructure = new RegExp(/(AW|DC|UA)-[0-9]{8,}(-[0-9]{1,})?/);

// Push IDs into dataLayer and set initial gtag/js?id= script to page using first ID in googleIds array
for (var i = 0; i < googleIds.length; i++) {
  var gtagId = googleIds[i];

  // Validate that the ID being passed isn't a big weirdo
  var idIsValid =
    typeof gtagId === "string" && gtagId.match(validIdStructure);

  if (idIsValid) {
    window.gtag("config", gtagId);

    // NOTE: gtag script only needs to be set to page once, but each gtag('config', <ID>) that's pushed to the dataLayer will add subsequent gtag/js?id=<ID> scripts to the page
    if (!gtagScriptExists) {
      // Set initial gtag/js?id=<first ID> script to <head>
      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.async = true;
      script.src = "//www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=" + gtagId;
      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

      // Update gtag/js?id= script status flag so this initialization script is only set for the first ID, and not all the IDs in the array
      gtagScriptExists = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for links to the docs. But I find the OP's code more straightforward to use than your snippet. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. You can add multiple accounts, and send to all of them or send individually.

Setup

```html
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXX-1">
</script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  // Global configs
  gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXX-1');
  gtag('config', 'AW-YYYYYY');
  gtag('config', 'DC-ZZZZZZ');

</script>
```

And this is the place when firing events

```html
<script> 
  // This is place firing event
  // Send to all

  // Send to one: Measure Google Ads conversions
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-YYYYYY/AbC-D_efG-h12_34-567',
      'value': 1.0,
      'currency': 'USD'
  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, that is correct according to documentation. But it generated no data for me on the subsequent codes until I added

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=ANOTHER_CODE"></script>
```

Immediately above the code block. Either I stumbled on a working kludge or Google needs to update their documentation.

Comment: It looks like each tracking ID you want to receive a Page View event, you'd need a separate `script` element with the `id` set to the tracking ID you want to receive the Page View event.  Sometimes you want this, sometimes you don't - depends on the use case.

Comment: with adding the script,  there is no data transferred to google analytics . I got 'Sending event "page_view" to undefined' in chrome console with google analytics debugger extension.

Answer (score 2):

That seems to be the official way to do it [according to the documentation](https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/devguide/add).

Comment: This documentation is for add another product, i.e. Google Ads, not another Analytics tracking ID.